# non-blocking and blocking concurrency

Tags: java, concurrency

As far as I understand - for example in `java` - when we are using `locks`, `synchronized`, `concurrentMaps`, `atomic` et al. we are using `blocking` concurrency as threads cannot proceed until the locks are released. Basically it uses `mutual exclusion`.

However in `non-blocking` concurrency we suppose not to use `mutual exclusion` and guarantee the progress of every thread as long as they do not contend for the same resource. But if they need the same resource it seems they become `blocking` again. Am I right?

What are `java` constructions for `non-blocking` concurrency and why do they called `non-blocking` if they rely on `mutual exclusion` in case of access to the same resource?

So what are `non blocking` facilities in `java` for concurrency

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest form of `non-blocking` code is to simply avoid locking or synchronizing. This gets you quite far actually.

If you use some resources that other threads also use (shared memory), you can use some `java.util.concurrent` classes. If you look at the API documentation, some avoid blocking in favor or relaxing some requirements. Usually only guaranteeing `eventual consistency` instead of immediate/atomic changes.

This gets you *almost* all the way. Unfortunately there are still some use-cases, like producer-consumer scenarios, network communication and I/O in general, where you can't really avoid "waiting" for something.

The cool thing is though, you can still write block-free code by using *continuations*. In Java this is basically `java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture`. The trick is that you don't write sequential code, instead you write what should happen if the producer is "ready". This way, you don't block any threads and your application is block-free.

So instead of:

```java
Item item = itemProducer.poll(); // <- blocks
consumer.consume(item);
```

You do:

```java
CompletableFuture<Item> itemFuture = itemProducer.get();
itemFuture.thenApply(consumer);
```

Or short:

```java
itemProducer().get().thenApply(consumer);
```

Comment: so basically `non-blocking` concurrency happens when there is no explicit `lock` involved? Inside it my still use some `locking` but as long as the programmer does not do it explicitely it will be non-blocking?

Comment: Not quite. Non-blocking really means your code does not block any Threads, even implicitly. Using `CompletableFuture` does NOT block. It really "makes" your code execute later on the producer thread actually.

Comment: But if `CompletableFuture` accesses some shareable resource  - it will need locking or not?

Comment: It won't need locking, because it represents a value that will be become available _later_. Your code in the `thenApply()` (or other similar) method will run _after_ the data is available. That means it does not need to block, because it is quite simply not running the whole time. It's a very neat trick.

Comment: Yes, there will be someone waiting. But usually, if you are doing it right, you can push the waiting code (almost) all the way back to the operating system kernel (for I/O)

Comment: So in the end it still relies on waiting for resource freeing but on lower levels? It is just not direct locking

Comment: For I/O yes, someone will block/poll (the network code that does select()). For other kinds of code however you _can_ avoid it entirely.

Comment: Then what is the difference with two threads that does not depend on common resource - for example one "adds 5 to variable A" while other "adds 6 to variable B". Will that state consider nonblocking?

Comment: The difference is you can add to the same "A". But instead of saying: "lock A, add 5, and in parallel lock A, add 6". You say "add 5 to A, _and when that is ready_, add 6".

Comment: So basically it is something like serialization of transactions? It is sequential but happens later.

Comment: Yes. It's basically sequential execution, but without locks to it, therefore non-blocking.

Comment: Oh! I get it now.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `java.util.concurrent.atomic` classes are the primitives that form the basis for certain non-blocking data structures in Java.

From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html):

> Atomic classes are designed primarily as building blocks for implementing non-blocking data structures and related infrastructure classes. The compareAndSet method is not a general replacement for locking. It applies only when critical updates for an object are confined to a single variable.

Answer (score 0):

AtomicXXX are supposed to be non-blocking / lockfree.